# Convert a JSON object to a particular CSV format

Tags: json, node.js, excel, csv, npm

I want to convert this

```
{
    "Name A":{
        "Name B":{
            "Name C":"Value C",
            "Name D":"Value D",
            "Name E":"Value E"
        }
    }
}
```

to this

```
Name A,,,
,Name B,,
,, Name C,Value C
,, Name D,Value D
,,Name E,Value E
```

It will look like this when opened in excel
[image]

I'm attempting to achieve this by running a small script, but before that I wanted to check if there is any node package or tool that can achieve this easily. Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by writing my own script. I had to tweak a little to fit my necessity according to the format of the data. It is not the most elegant solution. It was quick dirty solution I got working. Still it's a good reference if anyone wants to try writing their own script to convert JSON to CSV

```
var fs = require('fs');

var file = 'templateEn.json';

var content = fs.readFileSync(file, { encoding: 'binary' });

var obj = JSON.parse(content);

var jsonString = ""

var lineEnd   = "\r\n";

var firstLevelKeys = Object.keys(obj);
jsonString      += firstLevelKeys[0] + ",,,,," + lineEnd;
var secondLevelKeys  = Object.keys(obj["en"]);
secondLevelKeys.forEach(key => {
    jsonString     += ',' + key +',,,,'+ lineEnd
    var thirdLevelKeys  = Object.keys(obj["en"][key]);
    thirdLevelKeys.forEach(key2=>{
        if (typeof obj["en"][key][key2] === "string"){
            jsonString += ",," + key2 + ',"' + obj["en"][key][key2]+'",,'+ lineEnd;
        }
        else if (typeof obj["en"][key][key2] === "object"){
            var fourthLevelKeys  = Object.keys(obj["en"][key][key2]);
                jsonString      += ',,' + key2 + ',,,' + lineEnd
            fourthLevelKeys.forEach(key3 => {
                if (typeof obj["en"][key][key2][key3] === "string") {
                    jsonString += ",,," + key3 + ',"' + obj["en"][key][key2][key3] + '",' + lineEnd;
                }
                else if (typeof obj["en"][key][key2][key3] === "object") {
                    var fifthLevelKeys  = Object.keys(obj["en"][key][key2][key3]);
                        jsonString     += ',,,' + key3 + ',,' + lineEnd
                    fifthLevelKeys.forEach(key4 => {
                        if (typeof obj["en"][key][key2][key3][key4] === "string") {
                            jsonString += ",,,," + key4 + ',"' + obj["en"][key][key2][key3][key4] + '"' + lineEnd;
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    });

});

fs.writeFileSync("generated.csv", jsonString, "utf8");
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be you can try with this npm module `csvjson`.
The link is here:- https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvjson